# Redirect from several dynamic URLs to a unique URL

Tags: .htaccess

My actual and "desired" URL is (and works fine):

```
www.example.com/flower
```

The file is

```
www.example.com/indexmodelo.php?carpeta=flower
```

But I have the old URL to the same target  ruled by "IP" instead "carpeta"

```
www.example.com/indexmodelo.php?IP=202
```

And I need that when you put:

```
www.example.com/indexmodelo.php?carpeta=flower
```

OR

```
www.example.com/indexmodelo.php?IP=202
```

Go to:

```
www.example.com/flower
```

In my .htaccess fil I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/indexmodelo\.php\?carpeta=([0-9a-zA-Z_\-&=]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_\-&=]+)$ /indexmodelo.php?carpeta=$1 [L]
```

Thanks for your help folks!

Comment: If your end point is /flower only then you can redirect to it directly
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/indexmodelo\.php\?carpeta=([0-9a-zA-Z_\-&=]+)\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /flower? [R=301,L]`

Comment: No, because I used "flower" for the example. for each "carpeta" and "ID" I have several products...

Comment: You mean you want to redirect to the value of the carpeta from query string

Comment: YesYes exactly...

Comment: Allow only charset possible for value of carpeta in query string  `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/indexmodelo\.php\?carpeta=([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\s [NC] RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]`